# Grafana - configure a graph that shows cumulative delta over the selected time range

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Question best illustrated with a diagram:

[image]

I have data in Prometheus which tracks a financial balance over time. I'd like to graph this as a **delta**, starting from £zero at the beginning of the chosen Grafana dashboard timeframe.

I've tried a few different functions e.g. `rate`, `delta` etc, but these don't seem to achieve what I want.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer which works, although it's pretty complex:

https://blog.dest-unreach.be/2020/08/16/cumulative-graphs-prometheus/

```
my_metric
- avg_over_time(
    (
      my_metric and on() vector(time()) >= $__from/1000 < $__from/1000+$__interval_ms/1000
    )[${__range_s}s:$__interval]
  )
```