# Given a time series of absolute positions, how do I write a Prometheus query to calculate the distance travelled over a time range?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a time series called `position` stored in Prometheus. It represents the position of a linear actuator. I would like to calculate the distance travelled by the actuator over a given time range. Like this:

[image: Example graph illustrating the time series I'd like to create]

If I were to do this manually, I would take the absolute delta between each sample in the time series and sum them since the beginning of the selected range. I am struggling to piece together the correct PromQL query to achieve this.

I tried some queries like this:

```
sum_over_time(abs(delta(position[$__range])))
```

(I am using Grafana to perform queries, hence some template variables like `$__range`, `$__interval` and `$__rate_interval` are available)

This fails:

```
1:15: parse error: expected type range vector in call to function "sum_over_time", got instant vector
```

I have experimented with subqueries but the results I get change radically with the resolution and are not correct.

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73168096/grafana-configure-a-graph-that-shows-cumulative-delta-over-the-selected-time-r) but my input metric is a gauge rather than a counter.

What query should I write to get the illustrated output?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate distance you'll need to use [`idelta`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#idelta): it calculates difference between to latest samples of the metric.

Additionally, [`sum_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) accepts as input range vector, so you need to provide range selector for second time (and since it's applied over something more complex than vector selector, you'll need to use [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax `[range:resolution]`)

So, in result your query will look something like:

```
sum_over_time(abs(idelta(position[5m]))[$__range:1m])
```

Here, `5m` is range that is guaranteed to be bigger that your `scrape_interval`.
And `1m` is a `scrape_interval` exactly. Adjust to your situation accordingly.

Please notice that this query is very sensitive to misses of metrics, and might produce incorrect results.

---

Additionally, it might not start from 0 on the left of panel (if there is any positional data before what shown in panel). Let's say your dashboard has time range of one hour. Then every data point will represent how much actuator traveled over last hour before time of that data point.

If you need each graph to start from 0, and only increase from there, you could try and replace inside of `idelta` with something like

```
position{mode="idle"} and on() timestamp(position)>timestamp(position@start()))
[5m:5s]
```

But I don't have any input data like this to properly test this, so you might need adjust it a bit (or not a bit).